# Order of appearance of tags (and tag shown on the title bar)

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Referring to the last puzzle I created ([The Secret Club](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16540/the-secret-club)) I first decided to put a generic [enigmatic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle) tag, because I didn't want to give away too much. Then I added the [lateral-thinking](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking) one, just to give a little more help and to put people on the right track (most of the solutions proposed were math-based, even if the real solution wasn't in any way related to mathematics).
Anyway I think that my puzzle is 70% [enigmatic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle) and 30% [lateral-thinking](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking), and I wanted the order of appearance of tags to reflect this.
On the contrary it appears to be FIRST [lateral-thinking](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking), then [enigmatic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle); the more problematic thing is that the title bar of my browser shows ONLY the first tag.
In my opinion this could be a limitation for some puzzles, and maybe a form of "distraction" toward people who's trying to solve them.

Is there a way to decide the order of appearance of tags? (I've tried to manually change it, deleting and re-inserting them in the order I wanted to appear, but nothing changed...)

Comment: I suspect the tags automatically come in order of popularity - a mod will probably be able to confirm this.

Comment: No, you cannot change the order. Tags are always shown sorted by how many questions are tagged with them.